# Unity video audio doesn't pause correctly

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

So I have multiples videos that I am playing in my Unity project. They all run off of the same script and the script starts and stops video and audio by using

```
myMovie.Play ();
audio.Play ();
```

and

```
myMovie.Pause();
audio.Pause();
```

It works perfectly for every video except for one.  When I pause this one video the audio keeps repeating the sound it paused on. For example if the audio was paused at the beginning of the word "what" the audio would sound like "whawhawhawhawhawhawhawha" until I hit play and then the audio would resume, or until I change scenes where it would go away. Even when the movie is closed and the line

```
audio.Stop ();
```

is called it keeps repeating until the scene is switched.  Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Edit:  here is the full code:

```
void Start()
{
    pauseButton.interactable = false;
    playButton.interactable = false;
    closeButton.interactable = false;

}

public void playMovie()
{
    GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = myMovie as MovieTexture;
audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audio.clip = myMovie.audioClip;
    myMovie.Play ();
    audio.Play ();

        pauseButton.interactable = true;
        closeButton.interactable = false;
        playButton.interactable = false;

    }

    public void closeMovie()
    {
        myMovie.Stop ();
        audio.Stop ();
        pauseButton.interactable = false;
        playButton.interactable = false;
        closeButton.interactable = false;
    }

    public void pauseMovie()
    {
        myMovie.Pause();
        audio.Pause();

        pauseButton.interactable = false;
        playButton.interactable = true;
        closeButton.interactable = true;

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your whole code?  I would suspect something like `audio.Pause()` being called every frame is happening behind the scenes, and you just overlooked it.

Comment: @KingCat Agree with you. That's very likely.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what @KingCat said, audio.Play() is probably happening every frame, along with audio.Pause(), leaving it on a constant loop.

Comment: I updated my original post, thoughts?